# 218 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 Firebase IOS PUSH Notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I have added Firebase SDK in XCode but when building it says Error: 218 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

[image]

I linked these FirebaseMessaging & FirebaseAnalytics

[image]

I have followed the complete Firebase guide but I can't be able to fix it, Please someone help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, remove either FirebaseMessaging or FirebaseAnalytics from Link Binary. it will solve your problem.